# One word for seemingly convenient

Tags: single-word-requests

For the sentence: "I envy your seemingly convenient reason for X."

The "I envy" is genuine. The guy I was talking to makes trips. Let's say we both ride motorcycles, and I envied his seemingly convenient reason to travel to some place. I'd like one, but I need to work at finding places to ride my bike to. I didn't know whether he went to that place out of obligation or because he liked it. If the former, seems like it'd be in bad taste.

Comment: snarky ? (I don't quite understand why 'convenient reason' alone doesn't imply some deceit...especially leading in with the snarky "I envy your")

Comment: The "I envy" is genuine. The guy I was talking to makes trips. Let's say we both ride motorcycles, and I envied his seemingly convenient reason to travel to some place. I'd like one, but I need to work at finding places to ride my bike to. I didn't know whether he went to that place out of obligation or because he liked it. If the former, seems like it'd be in bad taste.

Comment: excuse me! :)  The motorcycle trip example helps.

Comment: ... Your ability to rationalize owning a motorcycle.

Comment: "convenient reasoning" is used very frequently(idiomatically) to raise suspicion -- there is this "juicy" healine at NPR today: *Why Was James Comey Fired? Trump's Suspicious Timing, Convenient Reasoning* .  While you're trying to be polite, casting more doubt on whether it was 'convenient' with something meaning seemingly makes it worse, in my opinion.

Comment: You should incorporate your comment into your question

Comment: @MarkoGalesic Have you checked a thesaurus for synonyms of "convenient"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you mean ***knack***, as defined by [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/knack):

> 1. a skilful, ingenious, or resourceful way of doing something
> 2. a particular talent or aptitude, esp an intuitive one

Examples (semi-made up):

> I envy your knack for finding interesting places to travel to by
>   motorcycle.
>
> I envy your knack for arranging your life so that you can motorcycle to
>   Yosemite Valley at least once a month.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect he didn't really *need* to take the ride, then I think *pretext* could work. From [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretext):

> A purpose or motive alleged or an appearance assumed in order to cloak
>   the real intention or state of affairs

Comment: In formal or more serious conversation, maybe, but this was casual texting.

Answer (score 0):

### 'Excuse' or 'Good Excuse'

> I envy your *good excuse* for going on a motorbike trip.

A rather political example of this idiom from *[Chicago Tribune](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/nationworld/ct-analysis-trump-needed-excuse-fire-20170509-story.html)*:

> Trump needed a really good excuse to fire Comey; Comey gave it to him

The implication in the article is that the firing of the FBI director was both legitimate *and convenient* for the President.